# #include <atlbase.h> not found, file exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, atl

When using Visual Studio 2012 creating an MFC project is possible but it cannot be compiled. All the ATL-headers cannot be found. For example if i create a simple dialog based MFC application and i compile it as it is from the project creation i get that atltrace.h could not be found (included in afx.h).

So i searched my filesystem for atltrace.h and found it in "$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include\atltrace.h". Knowing that i searched the VC++ Directories in the project properties. For the include paths it says "$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);". So obviously the folder where atltrace.h is contained is a system include folder for the project and the file exists there. Even though #include  results in an error that the file does not exist.

Does anyone of you know why this happend?

Thanks in advance and greetings
Muepe

Comment: You actually have a directory named "$(VCInstallDir)" on your machine???

Comment: No, it was just to show that its the same directory as $(VCInstallDir). Its "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 11\VC".

Comment: What happened to "Microsoft" in that path name?

Comment: Is it atltrace.h or atlbase.h you're missing? The question title indicates the latter, while you're question (last sentence, first paragraph) indicates the former. Going out on a limb, my guess is no matter how many atltrace.h files you have on your system, it isn't going to help you find atlbase.h a bit.

Comment: None of them can be found, neither atlbase (if i include it or if MFC includes it) nor atltrace nor any other of the ATL header files.